# Модификаторы virtual и override

Tags: c#

Пусть имеется 3 класса A B и C. B наследуется от А, а C в свою очередь от B, следовательно B получит всё что есть у A, а C получит всё от A и B. И вот вопрос что будет происходить если в классе А имеется виртуальный метод void speak(), а класс B его просто переопределяет и также поступает класс С, и меня собственно интересует будут ли классы В и С иметь в себе базовую версию метода от класса А или  она каким-то образом скрывается при переопределении и допустим класс C получит лишь переопределённую версию от класса В,а самая первая версия метода из класса А вообще не дойдёт до класса С.

Answer (score 1):

Если в наследнике метод помечен модификатором `override`, то он полностью переопределяет поведение класса-родителя, связанное с этим методом. Однако в наследнике можно вызвать реализацию `virtual`-метода родителя с помощью ключевого слова `base`. Например, так:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I speak as A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Speak()
    {
        base.Speak();
        Console.WriteLine("I can also speak as B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrei Khotko, то есть к примеру у класса C уже не будет Speak метода в варианте класса А, поскольку B переопределил этот метод и С получит вариант метода В если не переопределит его?

Comment: @Mark все верно.